# Neo4j HA cluster - single instances block

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

8 instances form my Neo4j HA cluster (Neo4j version 2.1.2)
I perform benchmarks of the technology with news feed algorithms.
A single client concurrently executes 50 read(!) queries per instance, that target a [server plugin](https://github.com/sebschlicht/neo4j-server-plugin-graphity) deployed to all instances.
The benchmark starts after all instances did bootstrap the data from the master. Requests are distributed round-robin by the client.

If I use a cluster with 3 or 4 instances everything works just fine.
The load is spread uniformly across all instances (according to CPU load) and low request latencies are reached.

However, with 8 instances 2 of them immediately have high request latencies.
During 3 seconds they increase from 500ms to 10s and further increase with the benchmark duration, due to the high request rate.
CPU load of these instances is at maximum.
The remaining 6 instances now have low CPU load, because the client is still waiting for the pending requests.
If I don't fire requests against the 2 instances, the remaining 6 instances perform as expected.
If I change the order, the same instances are blocking, thus this is not related to the server id.
If I remove one of the instances from the cluster, the other is still blocking.

It seems that this is related to the specific instances, but the setup of all 8 instances is equal, since they are virtual machines.
The log files don't contain hints neither. All instances are marked as available in the master's `console.log`.
Any ideas what is causing this issue and how to solve it?
As a dirty fix I will start a cluster with 10 instances and just use 8 of them, but this isn't a nice solution.

**edit**:
I observed a similar behaviour due to the index creation on a node property.
The first request per node loads the index and waits 10s for it to become available, which is too less time in some cases.
I stopped the benchmark immediately. All nodes get a high CPU load and when the CPU became idle I simply restarted the Neo4j servers.
When they were up again, the index was available - in most cases.

Therefore this might an index related problem. What is the proper way to create indices in a HA cluster?

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code of your plugin, and also look into stack-traces of the affected instances (jstack <pid> or kill -3 <pid>)

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, didn't see your code? So the feed endpoint is called?

Perhaps a memory issue? the plugins are stateful so in case your Graphity-Instance keeps state it might eat up a lot of memory.

So please enable gc-logging and see if something comes up there.

Comment: Yes, the feed endpoint is called. If an endpoint is called the first time a Graphity instance is created. The Graphity instance is static, only a single instance is used. In case you did browse straight into the code you might want to see the [instance initialization method](https://github.com/sebschlicht/graphity-neo4j/blob/master/src/main/java/de/uniko/sebschlicht/graphity/neo4j/Neo4jGraphity.java#L51-L66) in the Graphity repository. I expect the problem to be related to the initialization. According to `htop` there is enough memory available, but I will check the GC log.